# Cloudfront returning 401 in response to requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I've got a rails app that's using cloudfront as the asset host.  Everythings fine, except when it comes to fonts. To get browsers to pull cached fonts from cloudfront, I'm using the [font_assets](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets) gem.  Unfortunately, it wasn't the magic bullet I was hoping it would be.

In config/environments/production.rb, I've got this

```
config.font_assets.origin = 'https://www.MyURL.com'
```

I've also got force_ssl set to true.

When I curl one of the fonts, this is what I see.

```
$ curl -i https://**<mycloudfront domain name>**/assets/opensans-regular-webfont-debcfe09b9fe1d259815c339e9ef4a9f.woff 
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Cowboy
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: f1215a95-603c-4b8a-acc9-077a292ee538
X-Runtime: 0.006937
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<**Origin Domain Name**>
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 05:23:18 GMT
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Via: 1.1 vegur, 1.1 87a5dc4906ffb6323c3ec65df37e46f1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 8EQxf_pJ-fAiEis8ztx9icjRbFy5CWPn_ccOFO-WjzgICN-_NSOing==
```

I'm confused as to why I'm getting a 401, given that the origin domain is listed in the cloudfront origins.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: May I ask your deployment structure? you have few options depending on that to set CORS

Comment: I'm hosting the app on Heroku and using Cloudfront to cache assets.  For Heroku, it's just a "push to deploy" structure.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have done this setup myself before don't remember doing something special.. however try CloudFront Distributions > Origins > Origin Policy Protocol> Match Origin.. You already have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<**Origin Domain Name**> so I don't see any issues there. Try this also.  Edit your CloudFront distribution Behavior to Forward Headers so .

Comment: Did you mean that I should edit my CloudFront distribution behavior to "Forward Headers to .", i.e. forward all headers?

Comment: yes, its worth a try

Comment: I gave it a try, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your site use http and HTTPS both simultaneously? In that case the CDN will cache the first request and its scheme. If the first request was over http, all HTTPS will get ignored even though the config is in the Cor. I'd suggest to pick one and invalidate the CDN cache and see how things go.

If you set the behaviour in cloudfront to forward origin header, then cloudfront will cache different copies for http and HTTPS and hence work for both schemes. But this performs inferior.

Comment: I redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS, so I believe that would avoid this issue.

Comment: Yes that should do it. Don't forget to delete existing caches.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder!  I invalidated the existing caches and suddenly...everything worked.  :)